# Can't create modal dialog from MFC DLL

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to launch a modal dialog from a DLL loaded by an MFC application.  I'm using VS2010 and both the EXE and DLL use MFC in a static library.

I call `DoModal()` in my DLL to launch the dialog, with the parent being a CWnd* pointing to the main window from the MFC app.  The dialog resource is in the DLL.

This eventually leads to the MFC library function `CWnd::CreateDlgIndirect`, which has this debug check:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    if ( AfxGetApp()->IsKindOf( RUNTIME_CLASS( COleControlModule ) ) )
    {
        TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: Creating dialog from within a COleControlModule application is not a supported scenario.\n");
    }
#endif
```

`AfxGetApp()` returns NULL so the code in the debug check fails.  If I compile in release, the dialog appears, but doesn't seem to work (all the fields are empty even though I set defaults, some button's don't appear).

I've tried adding `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());` to the top of the function that launches the dialog, and it doesn't make any difference.

What am I missing?

Edit: here's the code I use to call the dialog.

```
HMODULE oldResMod = AfxGetResourceHandle();

AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
AfxSetResourceHandle(GetThisModule());

CWnd wndParent;
wndParent.Attach(parent);

CExportOptionsDlg dlg(&wndParent);
dlg.project_name = project->GetName();

if (dlg.DoModal() != IDOK)
{
    wndParent.Detach();
    AfxSetResourceHandle(oldResMod);
    return false;       // cancelled
}

// ... (get some data from the dialog members) ...

wndParent.Detach();
AfxSetResourceHandle(oldResMod);
return true;            // OK
```

Comment: I think `CreateIndirect` is for modeless dialogs? You probably want `InitModalIndirect` before calling `DoModal` but it would be helpful to show YOUR code. The problem is not likely in the MFC debug assert but rather a bug in usage causing the assert to fail.

Comment: You might want to read Pat Brenner's (snr MFC engineer at MS) comments [here...](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/376123/warning-creating-dialog-from-within-a-colecontrolmodule-application-is-not-a-supported-scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you've actually created a CWinApp somewhere in your current module (DLL/EXE).

Every module should have one, and only one, CWinApp object. Typically, you would make the CWinApp object a global variable such that it is created and destroyed when the module is loaded and unloaded, respectively.