# Creating dialog from within a COleControlModule application is not a supported scenario

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, windows-7, activex

I am upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10. I tried to use activex (ocx) in Windows 10, but the program did not start and ended. I got the source and checked it, but compiling is not a problem, but when I make ocx and load it in another program and use it, "Warning: Creating dialog from within a COleControlModule application is not a supported scenario." is a debug message. Even if it is compiled and used in Release version, it does not run. The activeX program structure in question is used by creating CDialog inside.

**Can this situation be solved simply?**

//code

```
m_CamDlg.Create( IDD_CAMDIALOG, this); // <= There is a problem here

TRACE("CLiveViewCtrl OnCreate 3\n");
m_CamDlg.ShowWindow(1);
```

Comment: Does [Can't create modal dialog from MFC DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538896/cant-create-modal-dialog-from-mfc-dll) answer your question?

Comment: "m_CamDlg.Create(~" : When this code is executed, the program does not proceed with a debug message saying "Warning: Creating dialog from within a COleControlModule application is not a supported scenario."